# create-react-app using old version of react

Tags: reactjs

I'm using `create-react-app` and have updated `react` and `react-dom` to later versions, yet when I console log the version of react being used, it's still showing an older version.

**package.json**

```
"react": "^16.3.0",
...
"react-dom": "^16.3.0",
```

Then I log the version used:

```
console.log('React.version', React.version);
```

And it tells me:

```
React.version 15.6.2
```

How can I get `create-react-app` to use the newer version?

Reason for update, I want to use [React Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) which is only available from version 16.3.0+

Comment: I think you actually want to update `react-scripts`.

Comment: @ChaimFriedman I thought that too - i'm about 20 releases behind, is it safe to just jump to latest?

Comment: well, thats a good question TBH. I would suggest looking at the `create-react-app` releases and see if there are any breaking changes. They are pretty good about posting them there.

Comment: I think if you stay under version 2 you should be ok, but I would make sure before relying on this comment.

Comment: Weird... just installed CRA and got the latest versions of react